# error when trying to build aplication for production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

it throws me this error: `The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script`, when trying to build an application in react for production. I use two files: App.js and firebase.js. These are the imports of the `App.js`, and the `firebase.js` file (which contains the firebase access configuration):

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {auth, db} from './firebase'

import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  onSnapshot,
  addDoc,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  updateDoc
}from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-firestore.js';

import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged,signInWithEmailAndPassword,signOut} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-auth.js';
```

firebase.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-app.js";

        import {
          getFirestore,
          collection,
          getDocs,
          onSnapshot,
          addDoc,
          deleteDoc,
          doc,
          getDoc,
          updateDoc,
        } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-firestore.js";

import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged,signInWithEmailAndPassword,signOut} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-auth.js';     

const firebaseConfig = {
//my data

};
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
export {auth,db}
```

Comment: I think the require over HTTPS is not allowed. You should install firebase locally an import from the local module.

Comment: Have you already tried what @ErwinvanHoof said?